# Selenium Webdriver for Chrome on Linux fails with 'Permission denied' or 'session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a simple script that tries to login to a website with Selenium for C# like this:

```cs
IWebDriver WebDriver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://mysite.de/");

// Login
var tenantTextbox = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("tenantTextbox"));
var userTextTextbox = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("userTextTextbox"));
var passwordTextbox = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("passwordTextbox"));
var loginButton = WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("loginbutton"));
tenantTextbox.SendKeys("Tenant");
userTextTextbox.SendKeys("sysadmin");
passwordTextbox.SendKeys("password");
loginButton.Click();
```

There is no issue on Windows, but when running it in Linux, it fails with some errors.

1. The build is done for Linux (E.g. `dotnet restore -r linux-x64` and `dotnet publish --configuration Release -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained --no-restore --output publish/`. If I try to run `dotnet --roll-forward Major /srv/publish/UiTester.dll` (Roll forward is used because the app is on Net7.0 still, but Net8.0 is installed on the server), the following error occurs:

```
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
 ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Error starting process: /srv/publish/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager  --browser "chrome" --output json
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (13): An error occurred trying to start process '/srv/publish/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager' with working directory '/srv'. Permission denied
```

2. If I set `chmod +x /srv/publish/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager`, the issue is gone, but the following error occurs:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) (SessionNotCreated)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
```

3. According to several existing issues, it might be fixed by setting some options:

- `--headless`
- `--remote-debugging-port=60000`
- `--no-sandbox`
- `--disable-dev-shm-usage`

I tried setting all of them in various combinations, nothing changed the behaviour (Except if `--remote-debugging-port=60000` was set --> This lead to an error where Chrome told me that the dev port cannot be set somehow).

Does anyone have some additional ideas what I can check?

**Version information:**

- Linux: 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
- Chromium driver version: 120.0.6099.109 (Should be supported in Selenium.WebDriver 4.16.*)
- Selenium.WebDriver (NuGet): 4.16.2
- Dotnet (Server): 8.0.100
- Dotnet (Project): 7.0.404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't judge me, this is horrible stupid in my case...

I just needed to install the correct version of Chrome like this to fix the issue:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

And if that fails with unmet dependecies, just install them manually or with `sudo apt -f install`.

P.S. I also had to set the `--headless` and `--no-sandbox` options like this:

```cs
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless");
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```